# how do I access a named parameter in a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I'm developing a REST web service using Node JS to work in conjunction with Backbone JS.
One of the REST methods is `GET /users/id/:id`, where :id is the id number of a user. This method will return the details of the user from a database.

What I don't understand is how can I pass the :id parameter from the url to the response handler.

I've defined the response handler in app.js like this:

```
app.get('users/id/:id',user.fetch(db));
```

and this is the user.fetch function

```
exports.fetch = function(db){
    return function(req,res){

        var id = ;//how do I get the Id from the request?
        console.log("id: "+id);
        if(id !== null){
            peopleDb = db.get('people');
            peopleDb.find({"_id":id},function(e,docs){
                if(e){
                console.log(e);
                }else
                {
                    res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
                    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
                    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
                    res.writeHead(200);
                    res.end(JSON.stringify(docs));
                }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you want is unclear, at least to me.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'll try and make it more detailed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return function(req,res)
   {
      var id = req.params.id;
      console.log("id: "+id);
      // ...
```

this should works as expected. You can read more [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params)